# Max length of elementwise product of orthonormal vectors in R^n

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, inner-products, orthogonality

The problem: Given unit vectors $\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ with $\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v} = 0$, consider $p_n = \|\mathbf{u} \odot \mathbf{v}\|_2$ or the norm of Hadamard product of the two. What is the maximum of $p_n$?

---

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, the problem reduces to $[\cos \theta, \sin\theta] \odot [\sin \theta, -\cos\theta] = \frac{1}{2} [\sin 2\theta, -\sin 2\theta]$. And the maximum is therefore $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$. In $\mathbb{R}^3$ using spherical coordinates, it seems the maximum is again $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ (and since $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, $p_3$ can't be less than $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$).

But I was wondering if the conclusion is extendable to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and if there's a more intuitive way of seeing it rather than blindly following polar/spherical parametrization.

Comment: Which norm are you using? The maximal Euclidean norm of $\frac12[\sin2\theta,-\sin2\theta]$ is $\frac1{\sqrt2}$.

Comment: @GregMartin, That's right. Euclidean norm is used. It should have been $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: The only tip I can offer is that one can eliminate the dot-product constraint by writing (taking $n=3$ as an example) $p_3 = (x_1y_1)^2+(x_2y_2)^2 + (-x_1y_1-x_2y_2)^2$. Then we're "just" trying to maximize this quartic form for unit vectors $x,y$.

Answer (score 1):

Working on a rotationally invariant unit sphere, we are free to choose a nice simple u-vector
$$u = \frac{1}{{\sqrt n}}$$
and to construct the v-vector via Gram-Schmidt from an arbitrary $x\ne \lambda u$
$$\eqalign{
y &= x - u\,(u^Tx) \\
v &= \frac{y}{\|y\|} \\
}$$
With these choices the length function is radically simplified.
$$\eqalign{
p_n^2 &= \|u\odot v\|^2 \\
 &= \frac{1}{n}\|v\|^2 \\
 &= \frac{1}{n} \\
}$$
and we conclude that
$$p_n = \frac{\sqrt n}{n}$$